# Verifying proof that a shape is a parallelogram.

Tags: proof-verification

So I was tackling the following problem:

[image]

And here is my working:

[image]

However, I am unsure whether my proof is thorough as I think the shape could still be a rhombus? So I am just wondering whether the proof is satisfactory for part a.

Comment: A rhombus _is_ a parallelogram.  In fact, in your work, "there are no right angles" is unnecessary, as rectangles are also parallelograms.  Basically, you only need to prove that opposite sides are parallel.

Comment: So, please enter the important parts of your question—in this case pretty much all of it—as text instead of posting pictures of them. Your question should be comprehensible with images disabled. Moreover, images are neither searchable nor accessible to screen readers, nor do they show up in summaries.

Comment: @amd sorry, I will try and do this is future, but I am still new to mathjax, so may still rely on whiteboard images for the near future! However, I admit there was no need for me to take a picture of the question as it could easily be written out. If possible could you provide a link to a webpage that has all of the mathjax operations on it? (I found it once, but have lost it haha).

Answer (score 1):

Both rectangles and rhombuses are parallelograms, just special cases. It's instructive to try and construct a [Venn diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venn_diagram) of all the shapes you know about when you're not busy with classwork.

Comment: Ok thanks, now that you say it I remember being told things like all squares are just a special case of a rectangle (probably a similar story with a circle being a special case of an ellipse). However, by that logic, then a square is just a parallelogram, but to me that seems a bit strange as they look so different. Anyway, thanks!